# Does a ball spin more from left to right than it does from right to left?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, angular-momentum, drag

I swear that in a manual on tennis published by the German Tennis Association (Deutscher Tennis Bund) it stated as fact that all things being equal a ball will move more from left to right than from right to left if spin is applied. Could this be true? I no longer have [this manual](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0764114859)
published 14 years ago but it always struck me as puzzling.

Comment: This does not make sense from a physics perspective

Answer (score 2):

I think it refers to the ability of a right handed player/ left handed player to move more in one direction than in other. Nothing to do with physics. Even if it is meant to be scientific its totally wrong .Germans aren't always correct.

Comment: Neither are apostrophe's, apparen'tly  :-)

Comment: I'll take care of that. :D

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what he meant by that but he could be referring to an aerodynamic effect. The rotation influences how air flows around it, creating forces, just like lift in a plane. See, for example, Magnus effect: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnus_effect 
Of course, the direction of the curve isn't necessarily 'left' but it depends on the rotation.

Comment: Well, maybe for right handed people the spin imparted would have a left bias and for left handed a right bias? or vice verso

Comment: To clarify, the manual was saying that a left-handed server hitting with sidespin will get more spin than a right-hander serving with sidespin, even if everything about the swing is the same. in this article https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/60681/what-causes-a-soccer-ball-to-follow-a-curved-path Santa Claus' answer includes this sentence: "when a ball spins in a fluid it feels a force. A soccer ball's spin is most noticeable when it's spinning left-right"

Comment: In cricket I think its opposite