# Why do golf balls travel faster if they spin?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, rotational-dynamics, projectile, aerodynamics

From the book I have been given to read I found that balls spin due to the centripetal force but I am confused about how exactly the resultant force causes it to spin and move forward about the same time. It would be very helpful if someone could explain the reason behind it and also why would spinning cause it to move faster.

Comment: see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnus_effect

Comment: More on Magnus effect: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/60681/2451 and http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=magnus+effect

Comment: I see two possible meaning here. If you mean that the whole ball is traveling faster then you may have misinterpreted the fact that it travells *further* before coming back to ground that way. In that case see @Phoenix87's link. If you are discussion why one edge of the ball travels faster than the rest consider waling forward in the aisle of a commercial jet in flight...

Comment: Yes, it seems to me that the whole golf ball should not, in fact, be traveling faster. Please clarify among the options submitted by @dmckee.