# Why do ball makes curvature?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum, projectile, curvature, drag

Case 1: when a player kicks the ball in soccer game

Case 2: When a fast bowler swing the ball in cricket

In both cases the ball makes a curvature. How this happens ? Is there any Law of Physics behind them? Does both the case undergoes same phenomenon?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/60681/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Do you mean vertical curvature (up-down) or horizontal curvature (left-right)?

Comment: This question is about comparing soccer ball and cricket ball and their phenomeno.. which is different from the question you marked @ACuriousMind♦

Answer (score 1):

When a player kicks the ball up he imparts to the ball velocity in the required direction. This velocity can be split up into a horizontal component (let us say x direction) and a vertical one (y axis). Since there is no force any x axis, the ball distance v(x)*t in the x direction in time t. But since there is gravity acting downwards along y direction there is a negative acceleration and the y coordinate is slowed down(during upward motion) proportional to t^2. Hence x and y coordinate are not related linearly as required for straight line motion. But the y term is related by some sort of square of x term as a result of curvature or bending exists(since second derivative of y art x is non zero)