# Why do balls move in weird ways when spinning on a table?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, friction, everyday-life, rigid-body-dynamics

I have noticed that small solid balls move in curved paths when spinning on a table. Is this related to the Magnus effect? Why does this happen? Does this happen in an idealized situation where the ball is perfectly round and the table is perfectly flat?

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/518823/116463

Comment: I’m interested, but having trouble duplicating your observation.  What kind of ball are you spinning on what kind of surface?  Are you spinning it approximately vertically and then watching where it wanders?  With a marble on my table it is hard to make out a pattern in its path beyond seeking out low spots.  I can think of several phenomena at play, but I want to duplicate what you are seeing to know which effects are dominant.   I would not expect the magnus effect to dominate at spinning marble airspeeds.

Comment: I am using foosballs on a Kick Foosball table and using the kicks by the players to get the ball spinning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magnus effect probably doesn't have much contribution to such a trajectory, it occurs at higher velocities, and can be observed whilst solid sphere is immersed  in a liquid or gas. So Magnus effect can be observed in sports like tennis, football, baseball etc. In the case of foosball table, trajectory which you mentioned is caused by "massé shot". Very known technique in billiard. First of all object which touches the ball should be able to create big friction force(this is the reason why professional billiard players chalk their cue sticks). When cue stick hits ball with some force $\vec{F}$ ball can move on two different paths, it can travel in straight line or travel on curve. Important factor is where we apply this force, if we hit ball on the left side, its axis of rotation will be tilted to the right side. $\vec{F}_{friction}$ will be acting from table with direction to the left, thus creating trajectory which looks like a curve. You can probably observe parameters of trajectory by changing torque: $\vec{\tau}=\vec{F}$ x $r$  by this I mean increasing or decreasing $r$ which can vary from $[0;R], R$ being radius of ball. Change in torque can cause change in angular acceleration, which can have effect on trajectory. In Conditions where surface is perfectly flat, and balls are round this effect still happens, billiard table has a very flat surface and cue balls are also very spherical. Even though some Foosball balls don't have perfect round shape, I don't see reason for this effect to not happen.